# item value does not update in a bound wpf listbox with datatemplate set

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, listbox

It seems that I do something wring with the binding, but after a lot of tries and research I still didn't find why (all the examples I found were so similar to my implementation that I can't see what I did wrong), could you please help me with that?

I have a class called `GlobalConfig` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a property called Name.

```
public class GlobalConfig : XmlSoftLinkSerializer, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return _name; } 
        set 
        {
            if (_name != value && PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
            _name = value;
        } 
    }
```

An `ObservableCollection<GlobalConfig>` is bound to a `ListBox` (by setting the `DataContext` property of the listbox), and I have this DataTemplate for the ListBox:

```
<DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I also have a user control called `GlobalConfigUI` which is bound to the `DataContext` of the listbox (using ElementName).

Everything works fine here, but when I change the Name of the config, nothing changes in the listbox...
I checked and I know the `PropertyChanged` handler in the Name setter is called, also the object `GlobalConfig` is updated, but the listbox still displays the old name...

here is how the `GlobalConfigUI` is bound to the DataContext of the listbox:

```
<my:GlobalConfigUI x:Name="globalConfigUI1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=settingsListBox, Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and here is how the TextBox inside the GlobalConfigUI control is bound to the Name property:

```
<TextBox Name="configNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" MinWidth="380" />
```

I'm not completely new to WPF but I've used it only like 2 or 3 times, so I think there must be some kind of rooky mistake here, any hints?

Comment: how is INotifyPropertyChanged implemented? Could you post part of your code for your name property. I susspect the bug resides there.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, just posted the code

Comment: seems good. The only thing i do another way is that i would first write  _name = value;
and then call PropertyChanged.  check the answer i posted. if it is not set in textbox then UpdateSourceTrigger is triggered on losefocus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first remark, change your `TextBox` binding by adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Also about `BindsDirectlyToSource`, I rarely use it. Remove it and check again

Also, change your implementation to

```
private string _name;
public string Name 
{ 
    get { return _name; } 
    set 
    {
        _name = value;
        if (_name != value && PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));

    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried `BindsDirectlyToSource` out of despair, don't even really know what it does! I changed it and now it works nearly fine, thanks! there's just one thing: when I change the text, it seems to have one character missed in the listbox, for example if I type "test" the listbox shows "tes"

Comment: BTW, does your answer means that the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` should only be set on the control that actually changes the value? I thought that since I set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `TextBlock` it should listen to the `PropertyChanged` event of the `GlobalConfig` class...

Comment: Ok now i may also tried `BindsDirectlyToSource` but i would also add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to GlobalConfigUI DataContext Binding (without much hope). Try changing the order in the set function of Name first assign the value and then raise PropertyChanged event. (this has much more hope)

Comment: should have thought a little more before asking this lol! Firing the `PropertyChanged` event before setting the value had not a lot of chances to work... Thanks again, now everything works fine!

Comment: About the other thing you asked i tend to use it the way you say. Whatever is binded and is editable TextBox, Combobox, CheckBox i set it to `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. it is not a general rule ive read somewhere though

Comment: it seems quite logic to me now that I thought a little more about it, but I still don't get why it doesn't work by setting it on the element that should reflect the changes (in this case the `TextBlock`), shouldn't it also listen to the event?

Comment: TextBlock in general just reads the value any time PropertyChanged is triggered. TextBox can update it. But by default it will update it when it loses focus, so you must specify to it that it does this notification earlier by setting this property. At least this is what i ve figured out

Comment: so now I see why it didn't work, I could actually keep the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the `TextBlock`, but since the `PropertyChanged` event was fired before the `Name` property was actually set, it didn't show the changes in the listbox, was just a silly mistake which had actually nothing to do with WPF or the binding mechanism... Thanks for your help, and as you explained it in your precedent post, it is actually better to set it on the `TextBox` since the changes are reflected immediately